# How to bypass anti-scrapping mechanism with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium to access Singapore exchange.

But it always pops up this recaptcha:
[image]

So I used recaptchasolver but it still does not work. Anyone got any idea how to solve this?

Here is my code below:

```py
from selenium_recaptcha_solver import RecaptchaSolver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


test_ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'

options = Options()

options.add_argument("--headless")  # Remove this if you want to see the browser (Headless makes the chromedriver not have a GUI)
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={test_ua}')

options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

test_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

solver = RecaptchaSolver(driver=test_driver)

test_driver.get('https://www.sgx.com/securities/company-announcements')

recaptcha_iframe = test_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]')

solver.click_recaptcha_v2(iframe=recaptcha_iframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Site contains anti-scrapping mechanism, so even if you will resolve Captcha, it would turn it again as far as your browser is detected as automation browser.

To resolve this, you should bypass condition, which detects your browser as "bot".

Here are list of options that are usually used to bypass anti-scrapping mechanisms:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
def enable_stealth():
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    options.add_argument("--enable-cookies")
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

enable_stealth()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.sgx.com/securities/company-announcements")
```

In your case this list is enough.

Comment: Hi Yaroslavm, Thanks for your answer. But the Captcha still pops up:((

Comment: is it possible to do a fake ip address?